# Will making a Restoration Loop-Fortify Enchant. . . insane Fortify Sneak percentage make me undetectable?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So if I created a Restoration Loop-Fortify Enchant potion and enchant a piece of equipment with a crazy Fortify Sneak percentage; Will I be undetectable at all times, or only sneaking? My character's already godly enchanted; I'm just trying to go around practically invisible, without having to cast invisible and muffle/placing muffle enchant. Or is there a way to make the spell last "infinitely"(aside from recasting after interacting with objects. I prefer the prior.)

Comment: Only way to find out: steal something in front of someone ;)

Comment: To answer your 'will it make me invisible without sneaking question. Answer this. Will a crazy fortify one handed skill help you do two handed damage? (the answer is of course, no).

Comment: @Ids i know a better comparison. Will a insane high one handed skill help me hit things harder without hitting things? Since he is  not sneaking it really does not make sense to count the sneak skill to it.

Comment: @MennoGouw Well to be fair, isn't there a skill in the sneak tree that allows you to sneak while running, so isn't it possible that this will help at all times?

Comment: @Draedalus That running while sneaking skill just means while you're already in sneak mode, you can still "run" and it won't affect your detection.

Comment: Excessive stealth enchantments make you easier to detect.

Comment: I have a set of 4x57% sneak gear(+228% total) and shrouded hood plus all ranks of stealth and 100 sneak(sometimes blessing of Nocturnal). I can sneak right up to an enemy facing me in a decently lit dungeon and sneak attack them in the face. A super high sneak enchant via resto loop should make you undetectable while sneaking. Similar with lockpicking. A super high lockpick enchant makes the whole interface the sweet spot. Maybe you are thinking of pickpocket, where any enchant actually makes your chances go down(not sure about potions, maybe same with them).

Answer (score 5):

Your sneak skill only affects yours chances of detection while sneaking.